# Cannot upload image to AWS S3 from NextJS app - on server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, next.js

I've got a problem with NextJS app. When I try to upload a file from localhost it works very well. The problem appears when I want to upload remotely. I host my app at Github Pages and when I what to do it I got 405 POST Error
[image]

I've checked the CORS

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "GET",
            "HEAD"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "ETag"
        ]
    }
]
```

and bucket policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::xxx",
                "arn:aws:s3:::xxx/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Localhost it works with the same code and the same file? Maybe try uploading with postman to make sure it's working. My guess is that something with content-type is wrong (I had this issue in the past´)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I found that the API request to Github pages is not allowed. That's why I've got 405 when I try to hit the https://example.com/api/awsConfit. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).